# iOS get intersection pixels between a UIBezierPath and an image

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cgcontext

I am implementing an app for coloring using `Swift 3.0`. I get a `CGContext` from a `UIImageView` and draw `UIBezierPath` above it in `UITouch` events methods - begin, move and ended -.

How can I get the intersection pixels between the context image and the path drawn? I need to get all pixel not only control points of the path.

Comment: could you add your code please and a screenshot ?

Comment: The technique will be similar to the one given here: http://robnapier.net/clipping-cgrect-cgpath. In this case, you'll want to include blending. Draw your image into a grayscale context. Walk through the context and make any pixel that is not black, pure white. Then draw your curve in black, with blending. Then walk through and find any pixel that isn't exactly white or exactly black. Those are the overlap. I can't write up the code for that right now in Swift, but it should get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're smoothing the bezier path and adding curves as the user draws, and not just using line segments? Otherwise you could just calculate the points along the straight lines between each touch point.

If you're using curved elements in the UIBezierPath, then you can get the points along that path using my library [ClippingBezier](https://github.com/adamwulf/ClippingBezier). The code would look something like:

```
for(NSInteger px = 0; px < [userDrawnPath length]; px++){
  CGPoint pointAlongPath = [[userDrawnPath bezierPathByTrimmingToLength:px] lastPoint];
}
```

It's fast, but you should probably cache the results as the user draws so that you're not re-calculating each pixel every time the user adds a new touch point.